# Is 'a career advice' grammatically correct?

Tags: articles

I understand it is an indefinite article, so does it really depend on how we mean 'career advice'?

I read an advertisement, "Need a career advice? - Contact ... " which I'm pretty sure is wrong

Comment: I cannot think of any context that it could be wrong, can you show what phrase got you confused?

Comment: If you asking "can the words *a career advice* appear grammatically in an English sentence, then the answer is yes. However I suspect you are enquiring about count and non-count nouns. Please give some more context. In this case please give a complete sentence that includes the phrase. English is a context-dependent language.

Comment: @AlexandreBorela - I can think of many contexts where it could be wrong. Most contexts in fact.

Comment: I read "Need a career advice? - Contact .. " which I'm pretty sure is wrong. Soo not taking advice from that person ;) but this got me thinking.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK UK That's the point I was trying to make, it's impossible to know without the context.

Comment: @AlexandreBorela can you think of a context where this could make sense?

Comment: So I was wrong, to me it made sense "a" because it thought it was referring to the "career advice", meaning one career advice.

Comment: @Alexandre: let me give you a piece of advice: if you want to talk about a single instance of a mass noun in English, put a quantifying word before it like *a grain of rice, a piece of fruit, a kernel of corn"*

Comment: "Career advice" is grammatically correct and idiomatic.  However, "advice" is an uncountable noun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Need a career advice? - Contact .. "

The above is clearly written by a non-native English speaker. "advice" is a non-count noun. The correct phrase is,

*Need career advice? - Contact ... "*

or

*Need some career advice? - Contact ... "*

Here's a context where "a career advice" is possible,

*John plans to set up a career advice bureau.*

In that case the indefinite article applies to the word "bureau".

Comment: Or *"Let me give you a piece of career advice."*

Comment: @PeterShor - Agreed (+1). However in this specific context, which appears to be a small ad offering the service, I think my versions are more appropriate. An ad saying *Need  a piece of career advice? Contact* ..." could appear sarcastic!

Comment: Agreed: your versions are much better for the ad (although arguably, my version is the correct grammar for what the ad was actually trying to say).

Comment: @PeterShor - I don't see that it is. Could you make yours an answer so I can comment on it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's worth an answer. But wouldn't they have said *"advices"* if they meant more than one? On second thought, maybe not.

Comment: I don't really understand the point you are making. Let's not get into a discussion in the comments :-)  I'd still be interested in seeing your answer.

Comment: +1 to the answer. I think the ad author understands "advice" as a synonym for "consultation".

Comment: @TimRomano -  Backatcha! Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Here's a career advice tidbit- don't hit on the boss's husband at the Christmas party.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - unless you are the boss!

Answer (score 1):

There is one very specific definition of "advice" ("an official notification, especially one pertaining to a business agreement" - dictionary.com) that would allow using "a" in front of it (though I would think at least you'd want to say "an", since advice begins with a vowel.) Otherwise, no. You can say "some advice" or "a piece of advice" but not "a advice." Maybe they meant "any"?

"Advice" seems to be kind of a cross between an [abstract noun](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/Abstract-Nouns.html/%22Abstract%20nouns%22) - something you can't use your senses to experience, such as "anxiety" - and a [collective noun](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/Collective-Nouns.html/%22Collective%20nouns%22), a word describing a group of things, like "team" or "flock." It's hard to think of another word that is exactly like "advice," though.